# Сравнение вершин в связном сортированном списке C#

Tags: c#, сортировка, сравнение, односвязный-список

Имеется класс вершины связного сортированного списка, реализованный на языке C#

```
class Node<T>
    {
        public T data = default(T);

        public T Data
        {
            get { return data; }
            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    data = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
                }
            }
        }

        public Node<T> Next { get; set; }

        public Node(T data)
        {
            Data = data;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Data.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Так же есть класс самого списка, но по факту он не является отсортированным. Хочу внести изменения в метод AddElement, чтобы список оставался отсортированным, но не понимаю как мне сравнивать значения вершин.

```
class LinkedSortedList<T> 
    {
        public Node<T> Head { get; set; }
        public Node<T> Tail { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }

        public LinkedSortedList()
        {
            Head = null;
            Tail = null;
            Count = 0;
        }

        public LinkedSortedList(T data)
        {
            CreateList(data);
        }

        public void AddElement(T data)
        {
            if (Tail != null)
            {
                var node = new Node<T>(data);
                Tail.Next = node;
                Tail = node;
                Count++;
            }

            else
            {
                CreateList(data);
            }
        }

        public void CreateList(T data)
        {
            var node = new Node<T>(data);
            Head = node;
            Tail = node;
            Count = 1;
        }
    }
```

Прошу помочь со сравнением вершин, что использовать IComparable, Comparer или что-то другое и каким образом?

Answer (score 4):

Добавьте constraint `where T : IComparable<T>`, тогда можно будет вызывать `t1.CompareTo(t2)` для значений типа `T`.

```
Node curr = Head;
while (curr != null && curr.Data.CompareTo(data) < 0)
    curr = curr.Next;

// позицию нашли, дальше вставка

var prev = curr != null ? curr.Prev : Tail;
var node = new Node(data) { Prev = prev, Next = curr };

if (curr != null)
    curr.Prev = node;
else
    Tail = node;

if (prev != null)
    prev.Next = node;
else
    Head = node;

Count++;
```