# 'T' is a type parameter, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, generics

Попытался использовать дженерики в методе, но получаю ошибку из заголовка, полагаю, компилятору не нравится, что метод TryParse может быть не объявлен для типа Т. Как можно исправить ошибку?

Полный код:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
                
public class Program
{
    public static T[] ArrayInput<T>() {
        int n;
        bool IsInt;
        do {
            Console.Write("Enter array's size: ");
            IsInt = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n); 
        } while (!IsInt);

        T [] array = new T[n]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            bool IsT;
            do {
                Console.Write("Enter {i + 1} member of array: ");
                IsT = T.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n); // ошибка
            } while (!IsT);
        }
        return array;
    }
    public static T[] SelectionSort<T>(T[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            int min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                if (array[j] < array[min]) // ошибка при сравнении
                {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            T dummy = array[i];
            array[i] = array[min];
            array[min] = dummy;
        }
        return array;
    }
    public static void PrintArray<T>(string name_of_array, T[] array) {
        Console.Write(name_of_array);
        foreach (T member in array)
        {
            Console.Write(' ');
            Console.Write(member);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        short[] unsorted_short_array = ArrayInput<short>();
        double[] unsorted_double_array = ArrayInput<double>();
        short[] sorted_short_array = SelectionSort<short>(unsorted_short_array);
        double[] sorted_double_array = SelectionSort<double>(unsorted_double_array);
        PrintArray<short>("Unsorted array of shorts:", unsorted_short_array);
        PrintArray<short>("Sorted array of shorts:", sorted_short_array);
        PrintArray<double>("Unsorted array of doubles:", unsorted_double_array);
        PrintArray<double>("Sorted array of doubles:", sorted_double_array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну T - это "любой тип", метода `TryParse` у "любого типа" нет, все логично. Но вы не рассказали, какую задачу вы решаете. Не ясно, как вам помочь.

Comment: На сколько я знаю, `.TryParse()`, это методы конкретных типов (`int` например), по этой причине о нем и правда вы скорей всего не сможете просто так узнать. Обычно в generic методах, для конвертации используют `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter()`, через который можно узнать о валидности (`.IsValid(..)`) и конвертировать (`.ConvertFromString()`).

Comment: Да ничего особого, сортировка выбором для двух типов чисел, просто хотелось вместо двух функций написать одну. И что, получается никак нельзя написать такую функцию для любого численного типа данных?

Comment: Кстати, чтобы _сравнивать_ числа неизвестного типа `T`, вам понадобится вот такой трюк: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1294376/10105

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите поддерживать числовые типы, то должно сработать так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
   Console.Write($"Enter {i + 1} member of array: ");
   while (true)
   {
        try
        {
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            array[i] = (T)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.Write("Wrong input, try again: ");
        }
    }
}
```

К сожалению, на текущий момент нету возможности сделать generic constraint на числовые типы. Но он [планируется в будущем](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/205).

Comment: `try-catch` - не круто :)

Comment: @aepot: К сожалению, я не нашёл интерфейса наподобие `Convert.TryChangeType`. А связка `TypeConverter.IsValid` + `TypeConverter.Convert` мне не нравится тем, что она вынуждена производить парсинг _дважды_.

Comment: Справедливо, плюсик поставил

Comment: @aepot: Это, кстати, классический пример [vexing exception](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/blogs/ericlippert/vexing-exceptions) (моя любимая статья, кстати)

Answer (score 2):

Как выше замечено, `TypeDescriptor` - полезная штука. Я добавил ограничение на `IConvertible`, чтобы случайно непреобразуемый тип не подставить.

```cs
public static T[] ArrayInput<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter array's size: ");
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n) || n <= 0);

    T[] array = new T[n];

    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Console.Write($"Enter {i + 1} member of array: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (converter.IsValid(input))
            {
                array[i] = (T)converter.ConvertFromString(input);
                break;
            }
        } 
    }
    return array;
}
```